# Where is git mv in SourceTree?

Tags: git, git-gui, atlassian-sourcetree

I know you can move files.  But what about renaming and moving whole directories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Actions** menu, **Move...** option at the bottom of the dropdown. Alternatively, the command line `git` command always works.

Comment: You can surely rename a directory to where you want it from the command line, and git should "see" that change without a problem.

Comment: Git sees the as deleted/new files which I do not prefer because of potential merge conflicts.

Comment: I don't see the Move.. option under Actions. Has this option been removed? There is a Copy option at the bottom, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `git mv` command on the command line after which SourceTree correctly indicated the move. The SourceTree command line can be opened with the `Terminal` button.

There is no way currently to do this directly inside SourceTree unfortunately, at least for a folder.